# How to link to a div using the hash sign in a Webmatrix CSHTML page

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I'm trying to link to a div in order to go a a specific section of a page. For example:

```
<div id="1112223333">
    <p>Show info about phone number 1112223333</p>
</div>
```

In an HTML page you do can get there by linking to

```
page.html#1112223333
```

I'm trying the same thing with my Webmatrix CSHTML code doing:

```
http://localhost:64053/Default.cshtml#1112223333
```

But it's not doing anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to the  ID attribute actually being an invalid value as according to the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) :

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

I would recommend changing the name of your ID attribute to begin with a letter to see if that makes a difference.

Is the  element that you are targeting far enough down your page to actually determine if it is being used as an anchor? (*You might consider placing a significant amount of content above it to check this*)

Comment: Tested beginning with a letter and it shows same results. The question asked doesn't seem to be the issue but some other bug in the code. I'll still give you the answer because in principle you are right.